# how to display the alert when the iframe embedded video playing,pausing,buffering

Tags: php, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I am replacing particular div content with the respective iframe when we click on it using jquery, How to display the alert when the video in the dynamic loading iframe is playing,pausing,buffering.

Can any one tell me how to fix this issue..

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This Example : 
  <html>
        <head>
            <script src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"     media="screen" charset="utf-8">
        </head>
        <body dir = "rtl">
            <iframe id="player" width="640" height="360"   src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-cSFPIwMEq4" onload="floaded()" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
            </iframe>
    <script>
    //onYouTubePlayerAPIReady
    var player;
      function floaded(){
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          videoId: '-cSFPIwMEq4',
          events:
           {      
            'onStateChange': function (event)
                {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING)                                    {  alert("Playing.."); }
                else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED)
                   { alert ("Paused.."); }
                else
                alert ("Buffering/Video Ended");                

                 }
           }

        });
      }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
   <!-- <div id="player"></div>-->
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          //height: '390',
          //width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
         if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
          alert('Video Playing');
   
        }
  else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
          alert('Video Paused');
   
        }}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is 100% success ......try this. if any problem email me kishor00977@gmail.com